# How to print document to Bluetooth printer from windows mobile 5 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, windows-mobile

I am new to windows mobile development and searching for how to print document to Bluetooth printer using C#.Net. I have go through some blogs but not sure from where to start.

Below are the some information I found

Zebra provides an SDK for Windows mobile which has many examples, short sample applications, and even a demo utility. You just simply call the APIs provided and the SDK will make the proper connection to the printer via Bluetooth (or TCP) for you.

**- But I am not sure whether its free to use?**

Please help me to find better option for printing on bluetooth printer from windows mobile device.

Thanks in advance

-Nitin

Comment: If you want to know if the Zebra SDK is free, you (or your attorney) should read the license agreement that comes with the SDK download. SO is not for legal advice.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Zebra SDK is free. It is a fast an easy way to use there printer on windows mobile. But you are stuck to Zebra (if you ever change the printer vendor that might be an issue) and what there SDK provides.

You can go the free way and start your own printing lib and have full control over the code:
Before you can start printing, you need a connection to the printer. For Bluetooth you can use other free SDKs (with free source code) like inTheHand (32feet.net).

Further on you have to start learning the Zebra printer's language. That may be, for example, ZPL. You need to send commands to the printer to get something out.

Bluetooth printer can be connected to Windows Mobile (WM) by using a socket or a virtual COM port. 
Starting with virtual COM port is an easier approach, just call registerDevice with the right args to get back a new virtual COM port you can use to communicate with the printer. A problem may occur, if the printer requests a PIN. I did not yet find a native way to set this PIN from code and used 32feet libs to overcome this.

You may also use TCP/IP socket programming to communicate with the printer. If the printer is already paired with the WM device, it is an easy task: https://github.com/hjgode/btprint using a lot of MS BT API.

If you are not familar with printer languages like ZPL, ESC/P and need to print text only, you may consider using the commercial PrinterCE SDK. It frees you from knowing all the bits and bytes of printing languages.

You can find some demo BT/VCOM printing code at http://code.google.com/p/win-mobile-code/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FCommAppCFbtSearch%253Fstate%253Dclosed (CommApp... folders).